# My flutter project failed to run on Android device & it's mentioning some Licenses issue

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle, sdk, gradle-task

My flutter SDK path is under `C:\flutter`.

I have the following error when running `flutter run`:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 in C:\Users\khaled\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 28 in C:\Users\khaled\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;28.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3
     platforms;android-28 Android SDK Platform 28
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\khaled\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 20m 16s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: can you try this ? https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/3687#issuecomment-455885806

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal
2. Type this command below command:
   `flutter doctor --android-licenses`
3. It will ask you 2 options:*(y/N)*, press 'y' for each license and keep pressing "Enter",
   for each license until it shows *All licenses accepted*